# Condition while update cypher query

Tags: neo4j, conditional-statements, cypher

I can't find simple solution to perform conditional update in one Cypher query.

Lets say I have **Game** node and the game has **State** property... 
I want the ability to do the following:

```
 If game.state = X then set game.state = Y else set game.state= Z
```

Is it possible to achieve in one Cypher query? your answer is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hello assaf_miz84, I can detail my answer more if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this to simulate the `if...else` statement:

```
START a=node(*), b=node(*)
WHERE a.state = X AND NOT b.state = X
SET a.state = Y, b.state = Z;
```

First, the `START` expression will load all nodes. Then, the `WHERE` expression will choose all nodes with `state` equal to `X` and set them as `a`, and will choose all nodes where `state` is not equal to `X` and set them as `b`. Finally, the `SET` expression will set all the `a` nodes and set `state` to `Y`, and will take all of the `b` nodes and set `state` to `Z`.

Comment: Simply set `a` and `b` to the id of the specific node.